# Repeating an event until the actual mean equals the expected value (within a suitable degree of accuracy). How many times?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, normal-distribution, expected-value, standard-deviation

If I had a spinner, where each probability and value is known, how many times would I have to spin it to say that there is a 99% chance that my accumulated winnings' mean is within $0.01 of the expected value?

(I'm not asking for this specific problem to be solved, but how I would work it out given the data, goal range and goal certainty)

| Prize | Chance | Prize*Chance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \$10 | 0.1 | \$1 |
| \$8 | 0.15 | \$1.2 |
| \$5 | 0.2 | \$1 |
| \$2 | 0.25 | \$0.5 |
| \$1 | 0.35 | \$0.35 |

**Expected Value: \$4.05**

How many times to spin until I can say that: `$4.04 < average winnings < $4.06` (with 99% certainty)

I know that this involves standard deviation, but none of the youtube videos about seem to actually cover this sort of problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am guessing you are either expected to use the Chebyshev inequality, or the central limit theorem.  In both cases you can set up the inequality in terms of the event $$\left|\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) - 4.05\right| \geq 0.01$$ where $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. random variables. The Cheybshev inequality has no approximation but it is loose.  The central limit theorem involves some approximation but is tighter. The Berry-Esseen results mentioned in the answer below are ways to make the approximation bounds precise but I am guessing that is overkill for your purposes.

Comment: If we set the prob. of a 1\$ prize to $0.3$ instead of $0.35$ (otherwise, the sum of probabilities exceeds $1$), the mean and the variance become $4$ and $9.9$, respectively. In this case, the simple (Chebyshev inequality) approximation requires $9.9\times 10^6$ draws, whereas the second (CLT) approximation achieves the desired accuracy after $\approx6.88×10^5$ draws.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the CLT approximation (if the distribution of the average is hard to compute). Specifically, let $\{X_i\}$ be i.i.d. random variables with mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$, and finite third moment $\rho\equiv\mathsf{E}|X_1-\mu|^3$. Also let $\bar{X}_n=n^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then, for $a<b$,
\begin{align}
&\mathsf{P}(\bar{X}_n<a)+\mathsf{P}(\bar{X}_n>b) \\
&\qquad=\mathsf{P}\!\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n}-\mu)}{\sigma}<\frac{\sqrt{n}(a-\mu)}{\sigma}\right)+\mathsf{P}\!\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X_n}-\mu)}{\sigma}>\frac{\sqrt{n}(b-\mu)}{\sigma}\right)\\
&\qquad\le\Phi\!\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(a-\mu)}{\sigma}\right)+\Phi\!\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(\mu-b)}{\sigma}\right)+2\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|F_n(x)-\Phi(x)| \\
&\qquad \le \Phi\!\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(a-\mu)}{\sigma}\right)+\Phi\!\left(\frac{\sqrt{n}(\mu-b)}{\sigma}\right)+\frac{\rho}{\sigma^3\sqrt{n}},
\end{align}
where $F_n$ is the cdf of $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)/\sigma$, and the last inequality follows from the [Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem). Now you need to find the smallest $n$ for which the rhs is less than $1$ minus the desired accuracy level.